# How can I tell `apt-get update` to download only one file at a time?

Tags: networking, apt, debugging, parallelism

I have a machine where `apt-get update` hangs for ever with a "Waiting for headers" message, suggesting that one source is not responding. From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/640296) I know I can do `sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::http=true update` to identify the culprit. However, it is still complicated to find out which query is not responding, because `apt-get` seems to be making multiple queries in parallel.

**How can I can tell apt-get update to only download one file at a time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your apt configuration file:
Acquire::Queue-Mode "access";
or use it on the command line like this:
apt-get -o Acquire::Queue-mode=access update